# Is it possible to run a scheduled timer in a suspended app?

Tags: swift, nstimer

I've read several posts on creating a timer that runs in the background. Is it possible to create a scheduled timer that will continue to run once the app has been suspended/terminated?

Apple's own timer achieves this, but it's not clear how. I am guessing they send a local notification for the timer expiry, and maybe they undertake a date object comparison if the app is brought to the foreground while still in the countdown period. Is this a correct assumption? Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, what you're looking to do is not possible - since the amount of time your app is allowed to run in the background is limited to ~3 minutes. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34982487/7245977) for more details.

You could achieve your goal through the use of a push notification, but that would require a server and won't guarantee it is received at the perfect time.

You might also want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890766/how-to-create-an-alarm-clock-app-with-swift)

It also appears based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13676910/7245977) that you cannot set a timer in the standard clock app either.

**TLDR** - You can't create a timer app.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look for a different approach.